# Why the same letters have different size on my display?

Tags: display-settings, lg-monitor

I have an LG 22EA63V-P display, and naturally I use it with full hd size. But the picture is not too nice. My main problem is that the letters width is inconsistent. For example, I write a lot of IIIIIIIIII, they have not got the same width.

I use an HDMI cable to connect my notebook and my display, and the video card is an ATI Mobility Radeon HD 5145. Also I use Windows 8.1 with enabled ClearType.

Comment: Did you check the physical resolution of the display (1920 x 1080) vs the resolution of you video output? For good result they must be the same. Also you did not describe the connection you use. A digital connection usually has much less potential for picture quality problems.

Comment: What OS are you using?  If Windows, did you enable cleartype?

Answer (score 0):

It's an aspect ratio issue.
Your output display must have correct aspect ratio in order for all text to be properly displayed.
So go to ATi mobility control center and check the resolution outputed on the display. Change it to one that respects the aspect ratio of the display.